# удаление канала дискорд

Tags: discord, discord.py

как сделать команду что бы после ее ввода удалялся канал в котором она была прописана

Comment: Посмотрите соответствующий метод у канала в документации

Answer (score 0):

На сколько мне известно - никак.
Если канал ваш то можно используя Discord API запрашивать по таймеру список сообщений на канале и при нахождении сообщения с ключевой фразой вызывать метод .Delete() у канала который вы наблюдаете, если вы владелец канала.
Информацию по API дискорда и используемый метод смотри тут https://ptb.discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#deleteclose-channel
Было бы лучше если бы Вы расписали свой вопрос подробнее.